# How can I force js.erb to refresh Ruby code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, erb

I'm trying to get a list of the `data_file_names` for my XslSheet model into a `select` dropdown in my js.erb file.

I've tried the following in input.js.erb:

```
inputEx.registerType("button", inputEx.ButtonField, [
{
    type: "select",
    label: I18n.t('form.field.xsl'),
    name: "xsl",
    choices: <% if User.current_user %>
               <% if User.current_user.current_scope['ab'] %>
                 <%= XslSheet.where(:assetable_id=>User.current_user.current_scope['ab']).pluck(:data_file_name) %>
               <% end %>
             <% end %>,
    required: false
}], true);
```

I've also tried putting this in a partial and rendering it:

input.js.erb:

```
inputEx.registerType("button", inputEx.ButtonField, [
{
    type: "select",
    label: I18n.t('form.field.xsl'),
    name: "xsl",
    choices: <%= Erubis::Eruby.new(File.read(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views/admin/forms', '_xsl_sheet_names.html.erb'))).result(period: @period) %>,
    required: false
}], true);
```

_xsl_sheet_names.html.erb:

```
<% if User.current_user %>
  <% if User.current_user.current_scope['ab'] %>
  <%= XslSheet.where(:assetable_id=>User.current_user.current_scope['ab']).pluck(:data_file_name) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Erubis was required to render the partial as my input.js.erb is in the assets folder.

Neither of these methods work. I am required to clear the tmp/cache folder in order to see updated values in the select.
Once the cache has been cleared and the page reloaded, I am able to see updated values.

Is there any other methods I can try?

Edit:

Now tried to create a method in the XslSheet model and call it in input.js.erb.

xsl_sheet.rb

```
def xsl_names
    if User.current_user 
      if User.current_user.current_scope['Application'] 
        x = XslSheet.where(:assetable_id=>User.current_user.current_scope['Application']).pluck(:data_file_name) 
        x
      end 
    end 
  end
```

input.js.erb

```
choices: <% x = XslSheet.new %>
              <%= x.xsl_names %>,
```

This also requires the cache to be cleared before updated values are shown

Comment: Where is *input.js.erb* located? If it's in `app/assets` that means it will be part of the asset pipeline, which should only contain static assets. Not assets that change for each request made.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yeah it's in app/assets.

I'm not sure how else I can manipulate the contents of the select without this file though!

Answer (score 1):

Everything in `app/assets` should be static and will be pre-compiled only once on the production server (meaning that the ERB will also be executed once). Reason you can use ERB at all is to correctly link to images and other static files. They will get a fingerprint and you'll need to use the asset helpers to correctly set the URLs.

Now on to solving your issue, since you want to have some dynamic JavaScript, consider making a `/js/:file_name` route that supplies the dynamic JavaScript.

```rb
# app/routes.rb
get '/js/:file_name', as: 'dynamic_js', to: 'javascript#show', defaults: { format: 'js' }
```

Now add a new controller for the route.

```rb
# app/controllers/javascript_controller.rb
class JavascriptController < ApplicationController
  FILE_PATH = "#{Rails.root}/app/views/javascript/*"
  EXT_REGEX = /[.]js(?:[.]erb)?\z/
  FILES = Dir[FILE_PATH].grep(EXT_REGEX).map { |file| file.sub(EXT_REGEX, '') }

  def show
    unless FILES.include?(params[:file_name])
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, # handled with 404 by default
            "Couldn't find JavaScript with file name '#{params[:file_name]}'"
    end

    render params[:file_name]
  end
end
```

Move your JavaScript file from

```
app/assets/javascripts/input.js.erb
```

to

```
app/view/javascript/input.js.erb
```

The last thing to do is update the usage. Since you most likely want to make use of the loaded static JavaScript files/libraries this file should be loaded after the static JavaScript assets.

```html
<%# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb %>
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <%# ... %>
</head>

<body>
  <%= yield # your main yield for all views %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= yield :javascript %>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above you can now use the [`content_for`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) method. You should now be able to create the following view.

```html
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <%= javascript_tag '', src: dynamic_js_path('input', format: :js) %>
<% end %>

<p>Your normal view content</p>
```

Alternatively if you need to load this specific script on every page you can just insert it into the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` directly.

You might also want to read up on [writing unobtrusive JavaScript](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript), which is static JavaScript that pulls dynamic data from elements. This way you can keep the JavaScript static, while essentially supplying arguments through the view.

If you want to know more about the internals of the asset pipeline, you can find them [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).